# what is a ksoap namespace?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap

please explain a little about the ksoap android objects. I couldn't find any help anywhere.

1. what is the meaning and purpose of "namespace" when declaring a ksoap object?
2. what is the purpose of "SoapSerializationEnvelope" object?
3. what is the purpose of "HttpTransportSE" object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KSOAP is a SOAP API based on kXML,where kXML is a lightweight Java-based XML parser designed to run on limited, embedded systems such as personal mobile devices

Check this link for details.
[Difference Between SOAP and KSOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425808/difference-between-soap-and-ksoap)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) webpage:-

> The ksoap2-android project provides a lightweight and efficient SOAP
>   client library for the Android platform.
>
> It is a fork of the kSOAP2 library that is tested mostly on the
>   Android platform, but should also work on other platforms using Java
>   libraries. It is still using Java 1.3 so should work fine on JavaME,
>   Blackberry and so on.