# HTML5 v/s Ajax-CE for smart tv app

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, smart-tv

I am developing application for Panasonic Viera Smart tv. I found development guide http://developer.vieraconnect.com/applications. It includes the Getting Started Guide, Device Guidelines, Technology Overview and many more.

In developing application in Panasonic Smart tv, I have heard & read about **Ajax-CE SDK** and **HTML5 SDK**.

- What is the difference between Ajax-CE SDK and HTML5 SDK?
- Why should i use one instead of the other one with examples?

Thank you SO!!!

Comment: Please see [Are questions asking for tutorials allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/are-questions-asking-for-tutorials-allowed)

Comment: @Quentin its wrong, you can see so many question which have inner question also & in link which you gave has two questions,Are such questions allowed? Aren't they not constructive? don't get me wrong you have much experience...

Comment: "its wrong, you can see so many question which have inner question also" — I'm having a hard time understanding this sentence. Are you suggesting that because the moderation process has failed for some inappropriate questions, those questions have become appropriate? That isn't the case.

Comment: "link which you gave has two questions" — Yes, and the answers are "No, they aren't constructive; because they are not constructive they are not allowed."

Comment: @Quentin check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425808/difference-between-soap-and-ksoap/7426265#7426265 is this right or wrong?

Comment: Since it isn't asking about HTML5/Ajax-CE, nor is it asking for tutorial recommendations, I don't see what relevance it has to anything discussed here.

Comment: @Quentin First question is HTML5/Ajax-CE which is better to develop app & why? Second question is examples & tutorial for guidance because i am not getting much help for Panasonic smart tv app development.

Comment: @Quentin now my question is right? can i ask for tutorial & examples in so in other question.

Answer (score 2):

In regard to *"Why should I use one instead of the other one with examples?"*

[Quote](http://developer.vieraconnect.com/intro/development-guide/device-guidelines) from Device Guidelines:

> **Device Guidelines**
>
> Both SDKs support a separate set of devices. For
>   details, see below for each of the SDK:

Comment: Thanks for answer this is one difference that i know but i want some tutorial, examples & any book which guide me & help me to start something in development...

Comment: panasonic E5 series TH-L-32E5D is supported HTML5 & Ajax-CE both or HTML5 or Ajax-CE?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax-CE is the technology used by Panasonic on 2011 TV/BD models and it is supported by 2012 models as well. Starting from the 2012 TV models the HTML5 is also supported, so depending on which TV series are required to be support you should decide on technology.

In general all TV vendors are moving to the HTML5 world - same happen with Philips, where the CE-HTML is not a requirement for 2012+ models (NetTV 4.x) anymore.